# TypeScript using generic type of generic type as value type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The question is a bit hard to explain without showing an example, so let's look at this `Message` type that will be extended and used as base type for other types.

```js
interface Message<E extends string = string, P = any> {
  topic: E;
  params: P;
}
```

I have this interface for indicading message type. The topic and parameters are generic to make sure the interface could be extend for different cases like:

```js
interface OrderParams {
  userId: string;
  orderId: string;
}

interface CreateOrderMessage extends Message<'orders.create', OrderParams> {}
interface UpdateOrderMessage extends Message<'orders.update', OrderParams> {}
...

type CustomMessage = CreateOrderMessage | UpdateOrderMessage | ...;
```

This allows me to add strict typing for `topic` and `params` for different topic types which I could use with a class:

```js
class PubSub<T extends Message = Message> {
  publish(message: T): void;
  subscribe(topic: string): void;
}
```

If we pass `CustomMessage` as a generic type to `PubSub<>` it will check typings for `publish` method, but I also want to make sure `topic` parameter of `subscribe` method is also type checked using `E` generic type of `T extends Message` generic type.

**So, is there a way to somehow extract generic type of another generic type so I could write something like below?**

```js
subscribe(topic: GenericOf<T, 0>);             // 1st generic of T type
subscribe(topic: TypeOfObjectKey<T, 'topic'>); // Type of 'topic' property of T type
```

Comment: Does `subscribe(topic: T['topic'])` do what you want? I think that covers at least your second example (`TypeOfObjectKey<T, 'topic'>`). Not sure what you're trying to do with the first (`GenericOf<T, 0>`).

Comment: @Wing haven't tried or aware of that, thank you! You can publish it as an answer

Comment: "Not sure what you're trying to do with the first (GenericOf<T, 0>)" - as I've said I wasn't aware of T[key] so I posted 2 examples whether it's possible to get generic of type or type of property.

Comment: Ahh ok, I didn't fully understand your question and thought you might be trying something like getting the first type in the union or something like that. Thanks for confirming :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subscribe(topic: T['topic'])` will ensure the `topic` parameter of `subscribe` is the same type as the `topic` property of the interface passed into the generic. Here's an example derived from the code you've provided in your question (I've made it error so that the underlying type is easily visible):

```js
interface Message<E extends string = string, P = any> {
  topic: E;
  params: P;
}

interface OrderParams {
  userId: string;
  orderId: string;
}

interface CreateOrderMessage extends Message<'orders.create', OrderParams> {}
interface UpdateOrderMessage extends Message<'orders.update', OrderParams> {}

type CustomMessage = CreateOrderMessage | UpdateOrderMessage;

class PubSub<T extends Message = Message> {
  publish(message: T): void {};
  subscribe(topic: T['topic']): void {};
}

new PubSub<CustomMessage>().subscribe('')
                                      ^^
Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type '"orders.create" | "orders.update"'.
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgcwgHgFFkIAPSEAEw2QzClB2QF5b7GAaZABReThABPAHzIA3gChkyMAHsADsAQAuZIQDcU5PLhQ4AWwyrumgL4SJoSLEQoA8lErRuugzUnSArhmgBJSqp0DCA4mtKyjn4BbMGhEuaW4NDwSMgAwlAQcJAOTlDoWLgoZBTUaJjYePgA5BF5GAB0CJnZENVcuc6uhqJi5lbJtsgAqvKUrZ35FUUk5BBUNAWVBLWRUI2eY63tyJMuej3iCWCC8ihp3nL6SzOsGVk5azd4yAA+I1uPec8QmhIIABs4FgeJ4AEYAZXB+AAKrNSotpi9WD9elp5OCAcAMAALAAU+iREFUMIAlKoAG6yYCUI5hWjgjDNYBgiB4uSKFTIGEAbWqHKU1QAuuTkFSaXT4hYQBAAO6gyHQi50WTXInCPGkhoYRnM1l46rVUlAA)